# How to get all parent folders of a URL. Each into one line in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I want to split `dfPagesTotal['fullsection']` which is currently a string like "`/sport/tennis/us-open`" into 3 news rows with

```
"/sport"
"/sport/tennis"
"/sport/tennis/us-open"
```

I tested something like this but just splits (and copies of course correct) but does not keep the the parent paths:

```
dfPagesTotal = dfPagesTotal.assign(fullsection=dfPagesTotal['fullsection'].str.split('/')).explode('fullsection')
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to split paths in every single row you might consider to use something like

## Data

```py
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame({"fullsection": 
                   ["/sport/tennis/us-open", 
                    "/sport/tennis/roland-garros"]})
```

## All parent paths

Next we can define a function that generate all the parent path as

```py
def all_paths(lst):
    out = []
    for i, l in enumerate(lst[2:]):
        out.append("/".join(lst[:2+i]))
    out.append("/".join(lst))
    return out
```

## Apply and Explode

Finally we can apply our function and the explode. Here I prefer to add an extra columns so we always know which one was the original path

```py
df["parents"] = df["fullsection"]\
    .str.split("/")\
    .apply(lambda x: all_paths(x))

df = df.explode("parents")
```

And the output will be

```sh
                   fullsection                      parents
0        /sport/tennis/us-open                       /sport
0        /sport/tennis/us-open                /sport/tennis
0        /sport/tennis/us-open        /sport/tennis/us-open
1  /sport/tennis/roland-garros                       /sport
1  /sport/tennis/roland-garros                /sport/tennis
1  /sport/tennis/roland-garros  /sport/tennis/roland-garros
```

Comment: simple and powerful :)

Comment: I get an "'float' object is not subscriptable" error

Comment: You should consider to share a sample of your actual data.

Answer (score 2):

This will help you.

```
df['name'] = ["/sport/tennis/us-open"]
ss = df.name[0].split('/')
ss.remove('')
new = []
pre = ''
k = 0
for n in ss:
    new.append(pre+"/"+n)
    pre = new[k]
    k = k +1
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"col":new})
df1
```

output:

```
    col
0   /sport
1   /sport/tennis
2   /sport/tennis/us-open
```

Note: this looks little hideous process. there should be a simple way.

Answer (score 0):

Another poteential solution is this one:

```
new_df = []
for i in range(3):
    dfPagesTotal = df.assign(fullsection=df['url'].str.split('/', i)).explode('fullsection')
    dfPagesTotal = dfPagesTotal[dfPagesTotal.fullsection != '']
    dfPagesTotal = dfPagesTotal.sort_values('fullsection')
    dfPagesTotal = dfPagesTotal.head(i)
    print(dfPagesTotal)
    new_df.append(dfPagesTotal)

new_df = pd.concat(new_df)
```

which gives:

```
               url           fullsection
0  /sport/tennis/us-open  sport/tennis/us-open
0  /sport/tennis/us-open                 sport
0  /sport/tennis/us-open        tennis/us-open
```